# Prevent saving the shipping address in Magento on checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

We are working on a project for a shipping carrier which works with a network of pickup points. The customer selects a pickup point (closest to their address) in the checkout, and picks it up there when their order has arrived.

The problem we are facing is that when a customer chooses to go through the checkout and immediately register, the customer shipping address that is being saved is the one from the pickup point. The real problem here is that we need the pickup point address on the order to be able to print the labels etc..., but need to prevent Magento from saving said address on to the customer so that they are not able to select it as a possible shipping address in their following checkout.

Ideas tried so far:

- Observer on "customer_address_save_before". It seems to let me prevent the saving of the address, but I can't detect whether it was called in the checkout process or not.
- Using the override where the pickup point address is saved. Setting the "save_in_address_book" to false has no effect (probably because we're registering).

Last idea I have is to simulate a guest checkout, but I have no idea how to do that.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I would have gone with the save_before observer.  Have you tried debugging or Mage::log()'ing?    You may just be having some issues configuring the observer.

And if the save_before doesn't do the trick, certainly a save_after where you clear out any address that was saved should be safe.

Comment: My observer is properly configured, the action is executed. The problem is that the customer_address_save_before action is called also when a customer manually adds or changes their address, and I only want to prevent the address from saving when a user registers via checkout.

Ofcourse, this is thesame with the customer_address_save_after event.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying.  I wasn't totally clear on what you meant by "can't detect whether it was called", but I understand now.

Is the shipping extension setting any custom attributes on the address that would allow you to reliably distinguish a user-entered address from one of these pickup centers?  

If not, you could update the extension to do so, but that's perhaps slightly less simple of a solution than what you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OnePageCheckout, check opcheckout.js, I think that is where the shipping address is saved using an ajax call.